# Android AlertDialog is not being displayed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm having difficulty making the AlertDialog show up. When a user clicks on the textView, the alertdialog is supposed to show up with an editText that displays the contents of the textView. Once the save button is pressed, the textview then displays the contents of the editText.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    final DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(this);
    TextView tvPassword;
    EditText etPassword;
    String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        //Get username passed down from loginActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        User user = new User();
        user = handler.getUser(username); //get user using username


        //Reference textviews with findviews
        tvPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);


        //SetText textviews
        tvPassword.setText(user.getPassword());


        //Create alert dialogs
        AlertDialog dPassword = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();


        //Create editTexts to place inside dialog
        etPassword = new EditText(this);


        //Set layout for dialog
        dPassword.setView(etPassword);


        //on clicking textbox, let user edit contents
        //***PASSWORD***
        dPassword.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                tvPassword.setText(etPassword.getText());
            }
        });

        tvPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etPassword.setText(tvPassword.getText());
            }
        });


        //NOW UPDATE DB
        handler.updateUser(username, tvEmail.getText().toString(), tvPassword.getText().toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `show()` on the `AlertDialog` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show dialog,Call `dpassword.show();`method.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity { 

    final DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(this);
    TextView tvPassword;
    EditText etPassword;
    String username;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        //Get username passed down from loginActivity 
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        User user = new User();
        user = handler.getUser(username); //get user using username


        //Reference textviews with findviews 
        tvPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);


        //SetText textviews 
        tvPassword.setText(user.getPassword());


        //Create alert dialogs 
        AlertDialog dPassword = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();


        //Create editTexts to place inside dialog 
        etPassword = new EditText(this);


        //Set layout for dialog 
        dPassword.setView(etPassword);


        //on clicking textbox, let user edit contents 
        //***PASSWORD*** 
        dPassword.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                tvPassword.setText(etPassword.getText());
            } 
        }); 
 dpassword.show();
        tvPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etPassword.setText(tvPassword.getText());
            } 
        }); 


        //NOW UPDATE DB 
        handler.updateUser(username, tvEmail.getText().toString(), tvPassword.getText().toString());

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I missed something so silly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `dPassword.show()` :D